# Reshaping dataframe on one column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas as follows

```
ID_1    ID_2    Date        Val
1234    1480    6/13/1970   10
1234    1480    7/8/1970    9
1234    1480    6/4/1970    8
1234    1480    4/1/1970    7
5567    1481    11/20/1970  25
5567    1481    5/25/1970   12
5567    1481    4/23/1970   9
8799    1482    12/23/1970  8
8799    1482    4/23/1970   7
8799    1482    9/26/1970   6
```

I want to convert this into another dataframe that has the following format

```
ID_1    ID_2    Largest Event   2nd Largest Event    3rd Largest Event 4th Largest Event
1234    1480    6/13/1970               7/8/1970          6/4/1970       4/1/1970
5567    1481    11/20/1970              5/25/1970         4/23/1970       NaN
8799    1482    12/23/1970              4/23/1970         9/26/1970       NaN
```

This is a subset of a much larger dataframe where I want the 10 largest events. The dates are already sorted in descending order of the `Val` column, so the sorting is not an issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `rank` with `pivot_table`

```
df.Val=df.Val.rank(ascending=False).astype(int).astype(str)+' Largest Event'
df.pivot_table(index=['ID_1','ID_2'],columns='Val',values='Date',aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
Out[629]: 
Val  ID_1  ID_2 1 Largest Event 2 Largest Event 3 Largest Event
0    1234  1480       6/13/1970        7/8/1970        6/4/1970
```

Update

```
df.Val=df.groupby(['ID_1','ID_2']).Val.rank(ascending=False).astype(int).astype(str)+' Largest Event'
df.pivot_table(index=['ID_1','ID_2'],columns='Val',values='Date',aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
Out[673]: 
Val  ID_1  ID_2 1 Largest Event 2 Largest Event 3 Largest Event  \
0    1234  1480       6/13/1970        7/8/1970        6/4/1970   
1    5567  1481      11/20/1970       5/25/1970       4/23/1970   
2    8799  1482      12/23/1970       4/23/1970       9/26/1970   
Val 4 Largest Event  
0          4/1/1970  
1              None  
2              None
```

Comment: I managed to create a rank in my original dataframe which is what i wanted, but the output is blank after using the pivot table command. Why did you use `df.Val` to be equal to the rank? I think that is causing some problem in my code. This is a great idea though, thanks!

Comment: yes, to make your solution scale for my dataframe i grouped by ID and then assigned rank.

Comment: Edited the original post to add more data

Comment: @HarshVedant just need to change this line `df.Val=df.groupby(['ID_1','ID_2']).Val.rank(ascending=False).astype(int).astype(str)+' Largest Event'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170571/discussion-between-harsh-vedant-and-wen).

Comment: This works, but instead of `aggfunc = 'sum'` i used `aggfunc = 'max'` to get the dates to display